# accessing errors thrown in console using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

is there a way in which we can get the list of errors in the console using pure javascript or jquery or any other client side script?

```
console.error("params")
```

just creates error, but I am not able to access the list of errors in console with it

Answer (score 2):

There's no build in function in javascript to get a list of all errors but you may use [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) to append the error message to an array each time you get one.

```
var myErrors = [];
startTrackingErrors = true;

window.onerror = function (errorMessage, url, lineNumber) {
    if (!startTrackingErrors) { return false; }
    myErrors.push({
      errorMessage : errorMessage,
      url : url,
      lineNumber : lineNumber
    });
    return true;
};
```

Here's a working [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kjHAWgs8Ax7tM6LTJS74?p=preview) (with error :P)

Comment: Glad that it helped, Cheers :)

Comment: What is `startTrackingErrors`?

Comment: Just a flag to make sure we track errors only when we want to. Keep it `true` if you want to track errors by default. Here's a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kjHAWgs8Ax7tM6LTJS74?p=preview)

Comment: In IE, it is not throwing an error in the console, but it displays "The content cannot be displayed in an iframe" :(
not sure how to solve this for IE as its not throwing error in console too

Comment: check out this plunkr in IE and chrome http://plnkr.co/edit/jJKFfZZX8GHQA0jJpj4r?p=preview

Comment: The reason for this is, that Google is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. As mentioned in [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror), some/many error events do not trigger window.onerror, you have to listen for them specifically. **X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN** is one of them :)