# Save log from chrom console by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a monitoring addon for the website.

Is it possible to get logs and errors from the chrome console by JavaScript?

I tried to override the console log and other functions but it only recorded logs generated by my own code.

I would like to catch logs and errors output by 3rd party lib as well. for example, if I am writing a website using jQuery I would like to collect all logs and errors output by jquery as well.

thanks

Comment: Im not sure if this is possible but you can preseve the logs this way: https://www.google.com/amp/s/arreya.com/kb/how-to-capture-chrome-browser-logs/amp/

Comment: Yeah. I am looking at using code to do this automatically. My objective is to save the console log in the background and use it for debugging unreproducible bugs. the end-user will not open the console before the error happens and the error may not happen again in a short period time.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510995/accessing-errors-thrown-in-console-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this?
You can modify the global console.log

```js
const overridedConsole = (function(originConsole){
    return {
        log: function(text){
            originConsole.log(text);
            // maybe save?
        },
        info: function (text) {
            originConsole.info(text);
            // maybe save?
        },
        warn: function (text) {
            originConsole.warn(text);
            // maybe save?
        },
        error: function (text) {
            originConsole.error(text);
            // maybe save?
        }
    };
}(window.console));

//Then redefine the old console
window.console = overridedConsole;
```

Comment: it only records data when the console is called by own code. Jquery error did not run through the function

Comment: There's  a typo on the last line, that should be `window.console = overridedConsole;`. @Alantod17 You've to override the console before any other code is loaded on the page, that way also a log from a third-party script will use the overridden console.

Comment: @Alantod17 If you run this script after the third-party script is loaded (e.g. jquery), 
Isn't it possible to overwrite the error log used?